# Scope в setInterval

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Нужно запустить функцию класса (ExtJS) по таймеру. В этом методе через this вызываются другие методы. Я почитал, что по таймеру функции запускаются в глобальном пространстве. Поэтому this там уже не мой класс. Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать через apply, вот простой пример:

```
var Test = function () {
    var self = this;      
    this.rnd = Math.random();
    console.log("constructor", self.rnd);
};
Test.prototype.get_rnd = function () {
    console.log("get_rnd()", this.rnd);
};
Test.prototype.get_rnd_delay = function () {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        return (self.get_rnd.apply(self));
    }, 1000);
};

var test = new Test();
test.get_rnd();
test.get_rnd_delay();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/s8GKn/

и мне кажется вас обманули - глобален не scope а context

Answer (score 0):

Выдрал фаербагом из DOM глобальное имя и в этой функции обращаюсь к другим не через this, а  глобально.
Если кто знает более элегантное решение, весьма прошу его здесь оставить)